remove empty cells, using text data from multiples cells from another sheets (some formula not working)

Using Google Sheets, I have this formula that takes text data from multiple cells from another sheets:
='24 KPI Weekly'!Z5&" / "&'24 KPI Weekly'!Z6&" / "&'24 KPI Weekly'!Z7&" / "&'24 KPI Weekly'!Z8&" / "&'24 KPI Weekly'!Z32&" / "&'24 KPI Weekly'!Z33&" / "&'24 KPI Weekly'!Z34&" / "&'24 KPI Weekly'!Z35 

It gives this as a result:
/ / Robert Bourassa / / / 1425 Rue des Mélèzes / / St-Blaise
I would like to remove the empty cell. I tried numerous ways that I could find on the web and none are working.
Among them, I tried with the TEXTJOIN function and added the TRUE function:
=TEXTJOIN(" / ", TRUE, '24 KPI Weekly'!Z5, '24 KPI Weekly'!Z6, '24 KPI Weekly'!Z7, '24 KPI Weekly'!Z8, '24 KPI Weekly'!Z32, '24 KPI Weekly'!Z33, '24 KPI Weekly'!Z34, '24 KPI Weekly'!Z35) 

But it is not working. It is not taking in consideration most of the cells from the other sheets (it is staying in black instead of being in colors in the formula. So therefore giving me an ERROR message. See screenshots attached. I tried others ways and it is always giving me the error message. As if those fonction do not work with my google sheets.
Can someone please help.

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

From the [tag:google-sheets] tag wiki: Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.

Google Sheets syntax varies depending on location
Using TextJoin can achieve your desired output. Instead of using a decimal comma notation in between your target range '24 KPI Weekly'!Z5, '24 KPI Weekly'!Z6, use semicolon (;)
I added a reference Explaining syntax differences in your formulas due to your Google Sheets location, that explains why the comma does not work on your end.
You can try this:
=TEXTJOIN("/";TRUE; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z5; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z6; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z7; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z8; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z32; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z33; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z34; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z35; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z59; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z60; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z61; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z62; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z63)

2nd Row:
=TEXTJOIN(" / ";TRUE; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z11; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z12; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z13; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z14; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z38; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z39; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z40; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z41; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z66; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z67; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z68; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z69; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z70)

3rd Row:
=TEXTJOIN(" / "; true; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z17; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z18; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z19; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z20; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z44; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z45; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z46; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z47; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z73; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z74; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z75; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z76; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z77)

4th row:
=TEXTJOIN(" / "; true; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z23; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z24; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z25; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z26; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z50; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z51; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z52; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z53; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z80; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z81; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z82; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z83; '24 KPI Weekly'!Z84)

Sample Output:




Reference:
TextJoin
Explaining syntax differences in your formulas due to your Google Sheets location

Hi. I am trying to answer you but I can't add any attached pictures here. So just to let you know that I will Answer to my question but this will be directed to you.

I have updated my answer above. You can try it, and if it does not meet your desired output, please let me know! @Fan H

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer

Thank you very much. This is working. And I clicked the accept button on the left (check icon)
